# Prove: $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x\in (1,3)$, $\left|\frac{5x^2 - 2x - 4}{5(x^2 + 1)}\right|\leq M$

Tags: proof-explanation

I am not sure how to find the correct upper and lower limits for this problem. I did find the breakdown of the inequality to be $\frac{5x^2+|2x|+4}{|5(x^2 + 1)|}$. Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Note that
for $x$ in that range, $5(x^2+1)>10$. Also, $5x^2-2x-4$ is certainly bounded, e.g., by $5\cdot 3^2+2\cdot 3+4$.

Answer (score 0):

$|\frac {5x^2 - 2x -4}{5(x^2 + 1)}|\le M \iff$

$-M \le \frac {5x^2 - 2x -4}{5(x^2 + 1)} \le M \iff$

$-M*5(x^2 + 1) \le 5x^2 - 2x - 4 \le M*5(x^2 + 1)\Leftarrow$

$10M \le 5x^2 - 2x - 4 \le 10M$.

Now $5 < 5x^2 < 45$ for $1 < x < 3$.

And $-10 < -2x - 4 < -6$ for $1 < x < 3$.

So $-5 < 5x^2 - 2x - 4 < 39$.

So if $M = 3.9$ then

$-10M < -5 < 5x^2 - 2x - 4 < 39 = 10M \implies$

$- M*5(x^2 + 1) \le -10M < 5x^2 - 2x - 4 < 10M \le M*5(x^2 + 1)\implies$

$|\frac {5x^2 - 2x -4}{5(x^2 + 1)}|\le M$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f:(1,3) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\frac{5x^2 - 2x - 4}{5(x^2 + 1)}$, $\forall x \in (1,3)$.
Then f is uniformly continuous on its domain.So, f can be continuously extended to $F:[1,3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Now F being continuous on a compact domain attains extremums. Hence there is some $M$ such that 
$| \frac{5x^2 - 2x - 4}{5(x^2 + 1)} | \leq M$.